# Duplication rules for Kolmogorov complexity challenges

Tags: discussion, duplicates, kolmogorov-complexity

While some challenges tagged [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) can succeed brilliantly, like my own first challenge which got me halfway to the rep cap and STILL remains my highest-scoring post network-wide, most others will fail with the comments saying that it "doesn't bring anything new".

I've even seen a few challenges closed as duplicates for this reason, which raises questions about what the rules should be for duplicates in the [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) tag. Questions like this one, right here on Meta.

Obviously, they should be closed in cases of plagiarism and such. But I'm curious to see what Meta thinks about this.

In each answer, describe circumstances that you think should be reason to close a [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

## The suspect has very similar structure to the target

If you can copy/paste your answer to the target, tweak a few literals, and get a good answer to the suspect, then it should qualify as a duplicate. I'll demonstrate with [Confirm the Illuminati](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/146499/62402).

This would count, since you can change a 10 to an 8 and change the characters involved:

```
       X
      \~/
     \~>~/
    \~>~>~/
   \~>041>~/
  \~>~130~>~/
 \~>~>~>~>~>~/
\~>~>~>~>~>~>~/
```

This might not count, since it removes 2 of the most difficult parts of the string to encode, the eye and the cap:

```
        /_\
       /_|_\
      /_|_|_\
     /_|_|_|_\
    /_|_|_|_|_\
   /_|_|_|_|_|_\
  /_|_|_|_|_|_|_\
 /_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_\
/_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_\
```